# Caption on the side of a figure

Tags: positioning, captions

Can anyone tell me how to get my caption on side of my figure, and at the same time aligned with the top of my figure?

Comment: Could you give us an idea how wide the figure is, and how wide the caption is? E.g., does the caption consist of just a word or two, or could it be several lines long?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the `\floatbox` and `\capbeside` commands provided by the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{A test figure with its caption side by side}\label{fig:test}}
{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{A test figure with its caption side by side}\label{fig:test}}
{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also be interested in the `tufte` document classes:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
  \caption{\protect\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The floatrow package is not compatible with the float package that I use for many things

Comment: The floatrow package is not compatible with the springer cls. Any other solution for the side caption?

Comment: @FJC Yes. I found it is not compatible with the `tabularray` package.

Answer (score 163):

Here is a *direct* and *robust* method:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.67\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2011-03-03}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \caption{
       Температура перехода в ионизованное состояние
       атомарного водорода в зависимости от плотности газа.
    } \label{fig:03-03}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Perhaps, this way is less smart compared to packages `sidecap` and `floatrow` mentioned in other answers, but I use it for many years because of its simplicity.  Widths of images and captions are fully controllable through arguments of `minipage` environment (`parbox` also works) and `\includegraphics`. Vertical alignment is controlled through optional argumants `[c]`, `[t]` or `[b]` of minipage`.

Comment: I found this much the best method. However, there is an issue with the behaviour of minipage and getting the alignment desired between the two elements (I wanted top/top) but this was fixed by adding a dummy line `\mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip]` immediately inside each minipage so it had a line to hang the alignment on.

Comment: Nice! However, I also had problems with getting the caption top-aligned. Adding dummy lines (as suggested by @Jack Aidley) didn't help either :( Please let me know if you have any other advice for the vertical alignment issue.

Comment: Yes, it is so robust that I can use it in the `subfigure` environment; the other the other two most voted solutions fail. It would be great, however, if someone may fix the problem @JackAidley mentioned about the top/top alignment.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get the caption underneath the figure, not on its side. I wish to place them on the left side of it. What am I doing wrong? Can it be a problem since I'm using revtex4-1?

Comment: @Sobi [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/15665) suggests adding `\vspace{0pt}` as the first item in each `minipage[t]` for top-top alignment. Basically, the `[t]` will assign the minipage's reference point to the _baseline_ of its content's _topmost_ line. The `\vspace{0pt}` adds a zero-height line at the top, so that's where the reference point will be.

Comment: I agree this method is better because it does not require extra packages and miniboxes are so useful in other contexts as well.

Comment: Also adding "[.3\textwidth]" as prescribed height before the width argument and "\vfill\hfill" at the bottom of the minipage will fill it out so that caption starts at top. At least if working with a square size box.

Comment: Looks like the smartest solution to me

Comment: This method is the best, it worked with me in LyX ert (insert tex code) very easily and perfect

Comment: @user1611107 Make sure not to add any blank lines in the figure environment

Comment: The advantage of the suggestion by @EvgeniSergeev is also that one can adjust the size of the vertical space above the columns if needed - for example, I was able to use `\vspace{-4pt}` to move one of the columns slightly higher.

Comment: It cannot break new lines.

Answer (score 25):

Use the sidecap package.

```
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics{fig}
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{SCfigure}
```

See [vertical position of sidecap figure w.r.t. top aligned caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113470/vertical-position-of-sidecap-figure-w-r-t-top-aligned-caption)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's simple and clean.

Comment: But how to determine which side the caption located?

Comment: This does not seem to work well when there is a linebreak in the content.

Answer (score 20):

```
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}    
\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
\caption{A test figure with its caption side by side}\label{fig:testA}
\end{SCfigure}

\begin{SCtable}
\caption{A test figure with its caption side by side}\label{fig:testB}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
\end{SCtable}

\clearpage

\begin{SCtable}
\caption{A test figure with its caption side by side}\label{fig:testB}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
\end{SCtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would not use package sidecap because it is incompatible with package float (and floatrow) and the author itself suggests to use alternatives (I remember such a discussion on dctt)

Comment: And I would _never_ use package `float` and if I use `sidecap` there is no need for using `floatrow` too! And if I use `floatrow` I wouldn't use `sidecap`! Long speech short sense: If one doesn't need `floatrow` then `sidecap` is the _better_ choice!

Comment: @Herbert: just out of curiosity, why do you say you would never use the `float` package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: too many problems when I forget that I shouldn't use `\restylefloat`. Everything can be done with the packages caption and/or floatrow

Comment: @Herbert: I agree about using `caption` and/or `floatrow` instead. Thanks for answering.

Comment: For future readers: [`sidecaps` seems to be incompatible with the `beamer` class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58267/latex-freezes-on-beginscfigure)

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to use koma script with 'captionbeside'

```
\KOMAoptions{captions=bottombeside} % topbeside
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{captionbeside}%
    [Example of captionbeside]%
    {Example of captionbeside, with inside caption. 
    Suspendisse justo purus, lacinia et, iaculis ac, sagittis at, enim. Nulla placerat, massa iaculis imperdiet tristique, dolor libero laoreet risus, ac sollicitudin enim sem vel ante.}%
    [i][0.8\linewidth][2em]
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/latex}
\end{captionbeside}
\label{fig:maincls.captionbeside}
\end{figure}
```

which has a similar command structure to floatrow.

Comment: AFAIK `captions=topbeside` would align top line of the caption to the baseline. The baseline of the graphics is at the bottom of the graphic. So, if you use `topbeside` instead of `bottombeside` you have to change the baseline of the graphics, e.g., using `\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\totalheight\relax}{\includegraphics...}`. Maybe you could add a second example using this?

Answer (score 8):

I am aware that this has been solved, however, I thought I would contribute what I use to address this problem.

I Create two new commands, as follows:

```
%----------------------------------------
%COMMAND FOR DOING SIDE CAPTION.
%----------------------------------------
\newcommandx{\mycaptionminipage}[3][3=c,usedefault]{%
    \begin{minipage}[#3]{#1}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{b}}{\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{t}}{\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}}{}
        \vspace{0pt}\centering\captionsetup{width=\textwidth} %Temporarily set caption width
        #2%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\newcommandx{\mysidecaption}[4][4=c,usedefault]{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
        %CASE ODD PAGES
        \mycaptionminipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\linewidth-\intextsep\relax}{#3}[#4]%
        \hfill%
        \mycaptionminipage{#1\linewidth}{#2}[#4]%
    \else%
        %CASE EVEN PAGES
        \mycaptionminipage{#1\linewidth}{#2}[#4]%
        \hfill%
        \mycaptionminipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\linewidth-\intextsep\relax}{#3}[#4]%
    \fi%
}%
```

These latter command take an argument representing the content along the outer margin (right hand side for odd page, left hand side for even page), content for inner margin, fraction of line taken up by the outer content, and, the alignment between the inner and outer content.

**Usage is as follows:**

```
\mysidecaption{<LINE FRACTION OF OUTER CONTENT>}{<OUTER CONTENT>}{<INNER CONTENT>}[<VERTICAL ALIGNMENT, c(default), b or t>]
```

**Here are Some Sample Outputs:**

1. ODD page:

[image: Odd Page]

2. EVEN page, via the same commands:

[image: Even Page]

**Full Working Example as Follows:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xargs,lipsum,caption,changepage,ifthen}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%----------------------------------------
%COMMAND FOR DOING SIDE CAPTION.
%----------------------------------------
\newcommandx{\mycaptionminipage}[3][3=c,usedefault]{%
    \begin{minipage}[#3]{#1}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{b}}{\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{t}}{\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}}{}
        \vspace{0pt}\centering\captionsetup{width=\textwidth} %Temporarily set caption width
        #2%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\newcommandx{\mysidecaption}[4][4=c,usedefault]{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
        %CASE ODD PAGES
        \mycaptionminipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\linewidth-\intextsep\relax}{#3}[#4]%
        \hfill%
        \mycaptionminipage{#1\linewidth}{#2}[#4]%
    \else%
        %CASE EVEN PAGES
        \mycaptionminipage{#1\linewidth}{#2}[#4]%
        \hfill%
        \mycaptionminipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\linewidth-\intextsep\relax}{#3}[#4]%
    \fi%
}%


%DUMMY TEXT.
\def\t{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Namlacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa.}

\begin{document}
    \section{Examples on ODD Page}
    \subsection{Image Outer, Caption Inner, Center Aligned}
            \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
            }{%
                \captionof{figure}{\t}%
            }[c]%
    \subsection{Image Inner, Caption Outer, Center Aligned}
            \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                \captionof{figure}{\t}%
            }{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
            }[c]%
    \subsection{Image Inner, Caption Outer, BOTTOM Aligned}
            \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                \captionof{figure}{\t}%
            }{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
            }[b]%
    \subsection{Image Inner, Caption Outer, TOP Aligned}
            \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                \captionof{figure}{\t}%
            }{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
            }[t]%

    \clearpage
    \section{Examples on EVEN Page}
        \subsection{Image Outer, Caption Inner, Center Aligned}
                \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
                }{%
                    \captionof{figure}{\t}%
                }[c]%
        \subsection{Image Inner, Caption Outer, Center Aligned}
                \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                    \captionof{figure}{\t}%
                }{%
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
                }[c]%
        \subsection{Image Inner, Caption Outer, BOTTOM Aligned}
                \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                    \captionof{figure}{\t}%
                }{%
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
                }[b]%
        \subsection{Image Inner, Caption Outer, TOP Aligned}
                \mysidecaption{0.5}{%
                    \captionof{figure}{\t}%
                }{%
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{name}%
                }[t]%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you can take the lazy way out (also robust) and use the `\sidecaption` environment defined by the Memoir class

```
\begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{title}[label]
the body of the float
\end{sidecaption}
```

Memoir also provides width, separation and margin location macros without forcing you to use Tufte or Koma design/layout solutions, and it allows you to use e.g. XeTeX.

Comment: I don't think, that usability of XeTeX is a special memoir feature. Even the standard classes allow you to use XeTeX.

Answer (score 6):

Somehow I cannot post it as a comment. This solution is basically what Igor Kotelnikov suggested above with the follow-up comments. It was convoluted a bit to get everything right, so I decided to post it. Go upvote the initial suggestion!

```
\newcommand{\sidebysidecaption}[4]{%
\RaggedRight%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}
    \vspace*{0pt}
    #3
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#2}
    \vspace*{0pt}
    #4
\end{minipage}%
}
```

With usage:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\sidebysidecaption{0.555\linewidth}{0.42\linewidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{saica13/images/cam_mounting.png}%
}{%
  \caption[Photograph of camera mounting]{Camera mounted between two
    projections screens. Note that while the view direction can be
    modified, the up vector of the camera is fixed.}
  \label{fg:cam-mounting}
}
\end{figure}
```

[image: an example]

Comment: Welcome to the site! You need 50 reputation points to be able to comment, I believe.

Comment: I changed `\RaggedRight` to `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}`, but that is probably because I use the `caption` package. I really like the `\vspace*{0pt}` gimmick. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

None of these is robust enough to work with the [beamerposter class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) within an environment such as the following:

```
\begin{frame}%
  \begin{columns}%
    \begin{column}{\colCWidth}%
        \tcbox[title=MOTIVATION]%
        {\begin{minipage}[t][.1\textheight][t]
         ...
         \end{minipage}%
        }%
     \end{column}%
  \end{columns}%
\end{frame}
```