# LaTeX freezes on \begin{SCfigure}

Tags: beamer, floats, captions

I need side figure captions but using `SCfigure` freezes LaTeX as described here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex-beamer/forums/forum/319190/topic/1589887

Do you have any solutions to this problem or any ideas of how to get side caption without problematic package?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A nice frame}
\begin{SCfigure}
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There seems to be a compatibility issue with the `sidecap` package and the `beamer` class. I just tested the `sidecap` package along with the article class and seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I propose your take a look at [Caption on the side of a figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29144/10898)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no requirement to use [`sidecap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sidecap) in order to create side caption in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). Some box manipulation would suffice. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A nice frame}
  \begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}\rule{4cm}{4cm}\end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{4cm}\caption{A nice figure}\end{minipage}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Depending on the shape of your image (or perhaps unknown dimensions), some changes may be required. However, fixes should be fairly trivial.

Regardless, you technically don't need to use `\caption` since there's no numbered image structure that will be referenced across `frame`s. You can just place the caption text using the same format/style if need be.

Answer (score 4):

First many thanks to Ian Thompson for providing minimal working example.
Secondly, I fully agree with azetina that this is a compatibility issue.
Now additional question - where should I submit a bug report in that case?
Last but not least answer provided by Werner is excellent but I just want to provide my alternative solution using columns.

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{columns}%
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{images/some-image}
        \end{column}%
        \begin{column}{0.53\textwidth}%
            \caption{some caption}
        \end{column}%
    \end{columns}
\end{figure}
```