# Caption on the side of a table

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

I tried to use the `floatrow` package together with the approach from the accepted answer from ([Caption on the side of a figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure)) to put my table caption to the right top hand side of my table. However, whatever I tried so far did not work out at all. I use the `float` package. Not very often but that is why I do not want to or cannot use the `sidecap` package which looks actually much simpler. I quickly tried the `minipage` approach which seems to work but not sure if I should use it. Here is my simple table which I used to try to bring the caption to the right top:

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[L] X[L]}

\toprule

AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\

\end{tabu}

\caption{This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the
caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the
caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the
caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help with this `floatrow` approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use a `KOMA-Script` class, you can use its `captionbeside` environment (adjust the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{captionbeside}
{This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption This is the caption}
[r][\linewidth][0em]
\raisebox{0.8\totalheight}{%
\begin{tabu} to .4\textwidth {X[L] X[L]}
\toprule
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}%
}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for this solution! Seems to work quite well. I just played around with the different parameters. The only thing which is a bit tedious is to adjust this raisebox parameter. Well, never mind, as long as it works :-)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with two subtable inside of a table environment