# vertical position of sidecap figure with respect to top aligned caption

Tags: sidecap

How to change the vertical position of a sidecap figure with respect to its top aligned caption? I want the caption to be right from the figure but align like in the attached mockup.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`verbatimbox`'s `addvbuffer` fails for long captions:

[image: addvbuffer]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
    \caption{\addvbuffer[5ex 0ex]{Foo bar}}
\end{SCfigure}

\begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
    \caption{\addvbuffer[5ex 0ex]{Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo
        bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar}}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add some information about your problem. The example is surely not enough to do anything that shots in the dark: how do you produce the text above the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Solution revised to handle long captions.  Place a vertical rule at the beginning of the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
    \caption{\protect\rule{0ex}{5ex}Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar }
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it fails for long captions. I added a picture and code to the original question.

Comment: The revised solution does not need verbatimbox anymore, does it?

Comment: @user1350789 Correct. I will remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the following to your preamble after loading the `sidecap` package:

```
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}
```

Or for center alignment:

```
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{c}
```

It's an undocumented feature.

Comment: This is really the best answer to the question (though maybe it wasn't implemented at time of OP?). I wonder why this is undocumented... Is there an option to pass to the alignment to a specific figure instead of setting and unsetting the option globally?

Answer (score 0):

Put the includegraphics in a minipage of matching width and insert an negative vspace.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Or use `trim` without `clip` in the includegraphics.

Comment: Hmmm.... this shouldn't be done; it can produce undesired results with the surrounding text: see the result of this simple example using your code: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}

aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa
\begin{SCfigure}[][!ht]
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{SCfigure}
aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa

\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I agree. Any idea how to do better?

Comment: Exactly which is the desired alignment?

Comment: I have a figure with a rule on the top but also some text above. I want to do align the caption text with the rule leaving the text in the figure a bit higher.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of the actual code you are using, showing how you are producing the rule.