# Sidecaptions next to sidewaystables

Tags: tables, captions, rotating, sidecap

I'd like to place a caption left/right next to my table which is rotated by 90 degrees.
So the caption should be next (e.g. bottom right) to the table and both, the caption and the table should be rotated. I use \begin{sidewaystable} for the actual rotation of the table, but how can that be combined with a sidecaption?

This sidecaption should only be an exception, all other table should have their caption top of the table (caption=tableheading)

```
\documentclass[caption=tableheading]{scrreprt}       
\usepackage{rotating}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \caption{This is the Table caption that should appear next to the table}    
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could place the caption in a `minipage`, similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29163/586 (you don't need a minipage for the `tabular`).

Answer (score 2):

Below I present you two options; the first one uses the [`hvfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package; the second one, places the caption inside a `minipage` and uses `\rotatebox` from `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass[caption=tableheading]{scrreprt}       
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[capPos=r,capWidth=0.4,capVPos=b,objectPos=c,rotAngle=90]
  {table}
  {\raisebox{\height}{\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
     \hline
     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
     \hline
   \end{tabular}}%
  }%
  {This is the Table caption that appears next to the table}%
  {tab:testa}

\clearpage

\vfill\begin{table}
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{tabular}[b]{ |c|c|c| } 
     \hline
     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
     \hline
   \end{tabular}\quad%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\caption{This is the Table caption that appears next to the table}
\end{minipage}}%
\end{table}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]