# floatrow + caption = odd behaviour + wrong figure numbers

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

Looking for means to control vertical alignment in subfigures, I decided to use floatrow package, but later found its behavior quite strange. The issue is with figure captions, which may disappear or have a wrong count.

Example:

[image: floatrow caption problem]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Here is Figure \ref{fig:test}:

\thisfloatsetup{heightadjust=all,valign=t}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{Caption that is missing.} % An error occurs when I place \caption and \label before \end{figure}  
    \label{fig:test}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption a}\label{fig:test1}
        \vspace{.5cm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[]
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}}
        {\caption{Test caption b}\label{fig:test1}}
    \ffigbox[]
        {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-c}}
        {\caption{Test caption c}\label{fig:test2}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
\end{figure}

As you see, figure caption is missing. Besides, Figure \ref{fig:working-caption-test} has got the wrong number.
 
\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{Caption that is not missing.}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:working-caption-test}
\end{figure}
 
\end{document}
```

What can be wrong? I have freedom to avoid using the package, so if anyone knows other ways of controlling subcaption+subfigure vertical and horizontal alignments, that will help.

****UPDATE****

I managed caption numbering, but the problem is with the heights of subfigures. All rows get the same height, so if A is small, there’ll be a rather large ugly margin beneath it. Placing `\thisfloatsetup` after the first `subfloatrow` does not help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Here is Figure \ref{fig:test}:

\thisfloatsetup{heightadjust=all,valign=t}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \ffigbox[]{
    \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox[]
            {\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
            {\subcaption{Test caption a}\label{fig:test1}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[]
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}}
        {\subcaption{Test caption b}\label{fig:test1}}
    \ffigbox[]
        {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-c}}
        {\subcaption{Test caption c (pretty long one xxxxx xxxxxxxx)}\label{fig:test2}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    }
   {\caption{Caption that was missing.}\label{fig:test}}
\end{figure}

As you see, figure caption is not missing any more and Figure \ref{fig:working-caption-test} has the right number. However, the height of subloatrow with A is bigger that it should 
 
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption that is not missing.}\label{fig:working-caption-test}
\end{figure}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure this helped me a lot for the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the `floatrow` package, so I can't help here, but maybe a solution with only `subcaption` would be fine for you:

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Here is Figure \ref{fig:test}:
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Caption that is missing.}\label{fig:test}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Test caption a}\label{fig:test1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Test caption b}\label{fig:test2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Test caption c}\label{fig:test3}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

As you see, figure caption is missing. Besides, Figure \ref{fig:working-caption-test} has got the wrong number.
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \caption{Caption that is not missing.}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:working-caption-test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks LaRiFaRi! Do you know how to make 1c aligned with 1b as in my example if they have different heights that are not defined in advance? That's the main reason I started using floatrow.

Comment: Type `texdoc subcaption` in your terminal and have a look on the cute animals on page 7. Easiest way would be to bottom align your graphics

Comment: My case is not ‘a cat and an elephant’, but more like ‘a bird and an elephant’. Figures must be aligned to top, but captions should remain on the same level. Being more specific, my subfigures are small table-like diagrams and I try to make their headers be next to each other.

Comment: Would it be an option to set the captions above the figures, as you do for the main caption? Alignment to top can be done by using [t] instead of [b]