# How to fix the space between "Figure" and "5" in "Figure 5:" in figure caption?

Tags: spacing, floats, horizontal-alignment, xetex, captions

I use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139508/79953) to get captions for my figures at the side, which works really fine. But sometimes, if the word behind "Figure xyz:" is too long for the line, I get something like this:
[image: Too much space between Bild and 4]

How can I control the space between "Bild" and "4:"? Can I somehow switch from justified to left-justified for this line if theres only this in it? Or can I insert a protected space there somehow?

Comment: Have you tried adding possible breakpoints? It is very likely that LaTeX simply doesn't know how to hyphenate the word.

Comment: This is my current workaround, but I hoped there would be a solution where I don't have to work on every caption manually.

Comment: If LaTeX can't hyphenate the word in the caption, it can't hyphenate it anywhere alese; meaning a global `\hyphenation{Pro-fil-quer-schnitt}` is best. On the other hand, trying to justify narrow columns is pretty pointless, because of those ugly spaces that will occur. Best to typeset the column `\raggedright` or `\Raggedright` from package `ragged2e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If LaTeX can't hyphenate the word in the caption, it can't hyphenate it anywhere else; meaning a global `\hyphenation{Pro-fil-quer-schnitt}` is best.
On the other hand, trying to justify narrow columns is pretty pointless, because of those ugly spaces that will occur. Best to typeset the columns `\raggedright` or `\Raggedright` from package `ragged2e` (allows hyphenation as well).