# How to align figure caption like this?

Tags: captions

[image]
How to align figure caption like this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caption on the side of a figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at [this answer to the posting "Caption on the side of a figure"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29144/110998).

Comment: Where is the figure supposed to be w.r.t. the caption?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[figure]{format=hang,indention=0pt,margin=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{White sand beaches. The pink smoothness of the conch
shell. A sea abundant
  with possibilities. Duty-free shops filled with Europe’s finest gifts and perfumes. Play
  your favorite game of golf amidst the tropical greens on one of the many championship
  courses.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```