# captions on the left side of the figure, in revtex4-1

Tags: captions, revtex, sidecap

I wish to place a caption on the left side of my figure.

I'm using revtex4-1 as follows:

`\documentclass[prl,amsmath,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4-1}`.

I wish to place the figure only on one column, with the caption beside it, not underneaph.

It seems that non of the solutions that I've found here: [Caption on the side of a figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure) 
work.

For example, using `\usepackage{sidecap}` and `\begin[SCfigure]... \end{SCfigure}` seems to fail.

What is the correct soltion which works for my document class?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with the error that you are getting when using `SCfigure`

Answer (score 2):

Please post a snippet of your code for us to see how it fails. Nonetheless, in my system it works perfectly fine. Try the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % you don't need this one

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{SCfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{black.jpeg}
    \caption{some caption that is used as a means to test the side caption of this figure}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

### Output

---

[image]