# Caption on the side of a Tikz drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

How can I get a side caption for a Tikz drawing?

If I try with SCfigure my drawing overlaps with the caption.

Here is the immage I drew using SCfigure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure} [b]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw  (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (-0.7,3) -- (-0.7, -3) -- cycle;
\draw  (1,3) -- (1,-3) -- (0.7,-3) -- (0.7, 3) -- cycle;
 \fill[black!15] (1,3) -- (1,-3) -- (0.7,-3) -- (0.7, 3) -- cycle;
 \fill[black!15] (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (-0.7,3) -- (-0.7, -3) -- cycle; 
\draw [<->] (-0.68,0) --(0.68,0);
\draw (0,0)  node[anchor=north]  {$h$};
\draw [<-] (1.01,-0.5) --(2.8,-0.5);
\draw (1.9,-0.5)  node[anchor=north]  {\small{K}};
\draw (1.75,0.5) circle (0.7);
\draw (2.2,2.5) circle (0.7);
\draw (-2,1.7) circle (0.7);
\draw (-1.75,0) circle (0.7);
\draw (-2.3,-1.6) circle (0.7);
\draw (2,-1.98) circle (0.7);
\draw [<->] (2.69,-1.98) --(1.31,-1.98);
\draw (2,-1.98)  node[anchor=north]  {$\sigma$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{I would love to have this caption on the left of my drawing :}
\label{entropic1}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (i) show small but complete document which demonstrate your problem (only with seeing it we can help you), (ii) it seems that your image is to wide ... (iii) welcome to tex.se

Comment: Thank you! 
How can I make my image smaller ?

Comment: @AndreaCerfogli change `[scale=0.5]` to the appropiate factor, and avoid the use of absolute units such as the `cm` you used in the circles.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to use `SCfigure`, there is no overlap when I try it here. Your diagram is certainly not so wide that you don't have room for the caption next to it, so resizing shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Latex gives me this error, but I don't know how to improve mi code
Overfull \hbox (84.33546pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 35--35

Comment: maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- as mentioned in above comments, for captions on side of figure (or table) is intended `SCfigure`
- vertical position of caption reggarding image you can set with `\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{m}` (m for middle, t for top and b for bottom /default/)
- with option you can determine ration between image and caption width (default is 1)

[image]

(red lines only indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{m}
\usepackage{tikz}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{SCfigure}[0.8][htb]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline]
\draw[fill=black!15]  (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (-0.7,3) -- (-0.7, -3) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!15]  (1,3) -- (1,-3) -- (0.7,-3) -- (0.7, 3) -- cycle;

\draw [<->] (-0.68,0) -- node[anchor=north]  {$h$}(0.68,0);
\draw [<-] (1.01,-0.5) -- node[anchor=north]  {$K$}(2.8,-0.5);

\draw   (1.75,0.5)  circle (0.7cm)
        (2.2,2.5)   circle (0.7cm)
        (2,-1.8)    circle (0.7cm);
        (-2,1.7)    circle (0.7cm);
        (-1.75,0)   circle (0.7cm);
        (-2.3,-1.6) circle (0.7cm);
\draw [<->] (2.69,-1.8) -- node[anchor=north]  {$\sigma$}(1.31,-1.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{I would love to have this caption on the left of my drawing :)}
\label{plates1}
    \end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

in above code i also make `tikzpicture` code shorter. as you see, image scaling is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. The first option after `\begin{SCfigure}` should be a number (the relative size of the caption). You have `[b]`.

This is the correct code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}

\begin{document} 
\begin{SCfigure}[0.5][b]
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
    \draw  (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (-0.7,3) -- (-0.7, -3) -- cycle;
    \draw  (1,3) -- (1,-3) -- (0.7,-3) -- (0.7, 3) -- cycle;
     \fill[black!15] (1,3) -- (1,-3) -- (0.7,-3) -- (0.7, 3) -- cycle;
     \fill[black!15] (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (-0.7,3) -- (-0.7, -3) -- cycle; 
    \draw [<->] (-0.68,0) --(0.68,0);
    \draw (0,0)  node[anchor=north]  {$h$};
    \draw [<-] (1.01,-0.5) --(2.8,-0.5);
    \draw (1.9,-0.5)  node[anchor=north]  {\small{K}};
    \draw (1.75,0.5) circle (0.7);
    \draw (2.2,2.5) circle (0.7);
    \draw (-2,1.7) circle (0.7);
    \draw (-1.75,0) circle (0.7);
    \draw (-2.3,-1.6) circle (0.7);
    \draw (2,-1.98) circle (0.7);
    \draw [<->] (2.69,-1.98) --(1.31,-1.98);
    \draw (2,-1.98)  node[anchor=north]  {$\sigma$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{I would love to have this caption on the left of my drawing} \label{entropic1} 
\end{SCfigure} 
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]