# Figure with long caption on side, wrapping under it

Tags: captions

I want to have a figure and a long caption on the side of it. I have seen several solutions to do this (e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure)) however if the caption is long then the result looks ugly. I want the caption to wrap under the figure as well. Here's my MWE to show what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{A really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption a really long caption}}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]