# How to put side caption in a figure that is wrapped inside a a text?

Tags: captions, positioning, wrapfigure, includegraphics, floatrow

I am relatively new and struggle to combine different packages. I am trying to wrap a figure within my text and I also want the caption to be aligned on the side of the text. My current approach looks as follows, while the red arrows show what I mean to improve:

[image]

In order to wrap the image within the text I am using the package `wrapfig` as follows:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace{-25pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.41]{figures/transformer3.png}
    \caption[Illustration of multiheaded attention]{Illustration of multiheaded attention. The two highlighted attention heads have learned to associate \textit{"it"} with different parts of the sentence.}
    \label{fig:transformer3}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent The projections are parameter matrices $\bm{W}_{i}^{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_q}$, $\bm{W}_{i}^{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_k}$, $\bm{W}_{i}^{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_v}$ and $\bm{W}^{O} \in \mathbb{R}^{hd_v \times d}$. By applying multiple attention heads, the model is allowed to jointly attend to information at different positions within the input sequence. In figure \ref{fig:transformer3} for example, the orange attention head associates \textit{“it”} with \textit{“The animal”}, while the green attention head has learned an association to “tired”.

\subsubsection*{Outlook on the Empirical Studies}
While the U-Net and the stacked hourglass are already well established architectures in the CV domain, Transformers have been mainly applied on NLP problems so far. However, there is a strong belief within the deep learning community that Transformers may represent a suitable architecture for CV tasks as well. For this reason, the empirical study will investigate on recent approaches to apply self-attention based networks on images. The concepts will then be implemented in a neural network that will be trained on a CV task. Finally, the performance will be evaluated against models that instead rely on the U-Net and the stacked hourglass.
```

For side captions, I read that the package `floatrow` should be useful. However, when I try to combine both, I get compilation errors. I also found an introductory usage [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure/291869). Again, I can reproduce this, but in this case I struggle to align it with my text appropriately. Can anyone help me out here? Thank's a lot!

Comment: I think that, for readability,  you should interrupt the main text for the whole height of the figure, which means you don't need wrapfig.

Comment: In this case I sort of agree with you. But in another section I definitely have to use it like that, because the image is so tiny. So it would basically be exactly the same setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same base setup is fragile. I would rather stick with two of them, one for floats which interrupt a text and one for `wrapfig` in text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, bm}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\makeatletter
\def\SC@figure@vpos{m}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font={small, sf},labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\noindent The projections are parameter matrices $\bm{W}_{i}^{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_q}$, $\bm{W}_{i}^{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_k}$, $\bm{W}_{i}^{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_v}$ and $\bm{W}^{O} \in \mathbb{R}^{hd_v \times d}$. By applying multiple attention heads, the model is allowed to jointly attend to information at different positions within the input sequence.
\begin{SCfigure}[50][ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.41]{example-image-duck}%{figures/transformer3.png}
    \caption[Illustration of multiheaded attention]
            {Illustration of multiheaded attention. The two highlighted attention heads have learned to associate \textit{"it"} with different parts of the sentence.}
    \label{fig:transformer3}
\end{SCfigure}
In figure \ref{fig:transformer3} for example, the orange attention head associates \textit{“it”} with \textit{“The animal”}, while the green attention head has learned an association to “tired”.

\subsubsection*{Outlook on the Empirical Studies}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{0.65\textwidth}
\vspace{-1.75\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} cX @{}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.41,valign=T]{example-image-duck}%{figures/transformer3.png}
    &
    \caption[Illustration of multiheaded attention]
            {Illustration of multiheaded attention. The two highlighted attention heads have learned to associate \textit{"it"} with different parts of the sentence.}
    \label{fig:transformer3}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{wrapfigure}
While the U-Net and the stacked hourglass are already well established architectures in the CV domain, Transformers have been mainly applied on NLP problems so far. However, there is a strong belief within the deep learning community that Transformers may represent a suitable architecture for CV tasks as well. For this reason, the empirical study will investigate on recent approaches to apply self-attention based networks on images. The concepts will then be implemented in a neural network that will be trained on a CV task. Finally, the performance will be evaluated against models that instead rely on the U-Net and the stacked hourglass.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer! I will work myself through it! :)

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to do it using `paracol`.  The only problem is that you have to manually split paragraphs using `\splitpar` and `\continuepar`.  OTOH, `paracol` is far more robust than `wrapfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, bm}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[font={small, sf},labelfont=bf]{caption}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\begin{document}
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-\columnsep}% second column uses remainder
\begin{paracol}{2}
\sloppy% SOP for narrow columns
\noindent The projections are parameter matrices $\bm{W}_{i}^{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_q}$, $\bm{W}_{i}^{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_k}$, $\bm{W}_{i}^{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d_v}$ and $\bm{W}^{O} \in \mathbb{R}^{hd_v \times d}$. By applying multiple attention heads, the model is allowed to jointly attend to information at different positions within the input sequence.
In figure \ref{fig:transformer3} for example, the orange attention head associates \textit{“it”} with \textit{“The animal”}, while the green attention head has learned an association to “tired”.

\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4in]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption[Illustration of multiheaded attention]
            {Illustration of multiheaded attention. The two highlighted attention heads have learned to associate \textit{"it"} with different parts of the sentence.}
    \label{fig:transformer3}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection*{Outlook on the Empirical Studies}
While the U-Net and the stacked hourglass are already well established architectures in the CV domain, 
Transformers have been mainly appl-\splitpar{ied on NLP problems so far. However, there is a strong belief within the deep learning community that Transformers may  represent a suitable architecture for CV tasks as well. For this reason, the empirical study will investigate on recent approaches to apply self-attention based networks on images. The concepts will then be implemented in a neural network that will be trained on a CV task. Finally, the performance will be evaluated against models that instead rely on the U-Net and the stacked hourglass.}
\end{paracol}
\continuepar
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank's a lot, I will definitely  try this one out too! :)