# Wrapfigure and Wraptable next to eachother

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

I have probably a stupid question and how do I get rid of the extra space in this extra space on top of my table.
[image]

This is what I wrote in latex.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %set encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %fonts

\usepackage{lipsum}

%languages
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{graphicx} %for including graphics
\usepackage{lastpage} %for inserting the lastpage number
\usepackage{pdfpages} %for including pdfs
\usepackage{wrapfig}  %for better text wrapable figures

\usepackage[labelsep=colon,justification=justified,labelfont=bf,textfont=sl]{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry} %for layout
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

% double Table caption fix
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false,
justification=centering
]{caption}

\newpage
\lipsum

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.6\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Messreihe und Histogramm von 10 Schwingungsperioden bei der}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \rule{\textwidth}{5cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{.3\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Table inside a wraptable}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    {} &    $T$ \\
    \midrule
    0  &  29.63 \\
    1  &  29.70 \\
    2  &  29.62 \\
    3  &  29.65 \\
    4  &  29.38 \\
    5  &  29.75 \\
    6  &  29.73 \\
    7  &  29.62 \\
    8  &  29.71 \\
    9  &  29.82 \\
    10 &  29.89 \\
    11 &  29.76 \\
    12 &  29.60 \\
    13 &  29.68 \\
    14 &  29.82 \\
    15 &  29.62 \\
    16 &  29.80 \\
    17 &  29.87 \\
    18 &  29.62 \\
    19 &  29.76 \\
    20 &  29.52 \\
    21 &  29.79 \\
    22 &  29.66 \\
    23 &  29.81 \\
    24 &  29.73 \\
    25 &  29.80 \\
    26 &  29.73 \\
    27 &  29.53 \\
    28 &  29.77 \\
    29 &  29.60 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:ta2}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: `wrapfig` is 18 years old. It has very unstable behavior. It often requires dances with tambourine and singing shaman songs to make it work. Therefore, a working minimum example reproducing the problem would be a good helper for others.

Comment: thanks didn't realise that the formatting was of and I could  have given a more general example

Comment: This is not going to work. `wrapfig` uses `parshape` to adjust *text* lines around a figure. It cannot place two figures side by side.

Comment: It worked with vspace :)

Comment: Well, the code you posted is not a working example. Working example is what I can copy&paste without guessing what packages, fonts, paper size you used. I guess I guessed wrong. Good you found a trick. However, it would be *really* helpful if you post an MWE next time.

Comment: you are totally right. sorry that I didn't include the packages I used

Comment: No worries. Welcome to the forum. :) I have an urge to write my own `wrapfig` in Lua. The existing package is unbearable.

Comment: Try using paracol instead.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591115/how-to-put-side-caption-in-a-figure-that-is-wrapped-inside-a-a-text/591155?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#591155 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer but it might not be pretty

```
\newpage
\lipsum

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.6\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Messreihe und Histogramm von 10 Schwingungsperioden bei der}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \rule{\textwidth}{5cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{.3\linewidth}
\vspace{6cm} % here is my dirty fix
\centering
\caption{Table inside a wraptable}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    {} &    $T$ \\
    \midrule
    0  &  29.63 \\
    1  &  29.70 \\
    2  &  29.62 \\
    3  &  29.65 \\
    4  &  29.38 \\
    5  &  29.75 \\
    6  &  29.73 \\
    7  &  29.62 \\
    8  &  29.71 \\
    9  &  29.82 \\
    10 &  29.89 \\
    11 &  29.76 \\
    12 &  29.60 \\
    13 &  29.68 \\
    14 &  29.82 \\
    15 &  29.62 \\
    16 &  29.80 \\
    17 &  29.87 \\
    18 &  29.62 \\
    19 &  29.76 \\
    20 &  29.52 \\
    21 &  29.79 \\
    22 &  29.66 \\
    23 &  29.81 \\
    24 &  29.73 \\
    25 &  29.80 \\
    26 &  29.73 \\
    27 &  29.53 \\
    28 &  29.77 \\
    29 &  29.60 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:ta2}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum
```