# How do I control the vertical extent of a Wrapfig environment?

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure, vertical, wrapfig

The Wrapfigure environment should only affect the top of the document. But it is still influencing the text after the first set of tables. I've played around with the \height, the negative \vspace and the \linewidth variables. Unfortunately, the "Hint" text is still only 0.7\linewidth. How do I make it the full 100%? I'm still new at Latex, and trying to convert my InDesign classroom materials into the new format.

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\linewidth}\vspace{-80pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=150pt]{ladder}
\end{wrapfigure}
    
\begin{center}
    \Huge{\textbf{Word Ladders}}\\
    \vspace*{8mm}
    \normalsize
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
Change one letter from each word to go from the top word to the bottom word.
\vspace*{3mm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
    
Here is an example. Go from \textbf{poor} to \textbf{rich} in six steps. The changed letter is \underline{underlined}.
\vspace*{5mm}   

\large
\begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){|c:c:c:c|}{|c:c:c:c:c:c:c|}
\textbf{P} & \textbf{O} & \textbf{O} & \textbf{R} \\
\normalsize \textit{b}  & \textit{o}    &  \textit{o} &  \textit{\underline{r}}\\
\normalsize \textit{b}  & \textit{o}    &  \textit{o} &  \textit{\underline{k}}\\
\normalsize \textit{\underline{r}}  & \textit{o}    &  \textit{o} &  \textit{k}\\ 
\normalsize \textit{r}  & \textit{o}    &  \textit{\underline{c}} &  \textit{k}\\
\normalsize \textit{r}  & \textit{\underline{i}}    &  \textit{c} &  \textit{k}\\
\textbf{\underline{R}} & \textbf{I} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{H}
\end{TAB}
%
\hspace*{5mm}
\large
\begin{TAB}(@,9cm,1cm){l}{|c:c:c:c:c:c:c|}
    \textbf{Start}\\
    \textbf{1} \hspace{3mm}\emph{a boring person}\\%boor
    \textbf{2} \hspace{3mm}\emph{something to read}\\%book
    \textbf{3} \hspace{3mm}\emph{a chess piece}\\%rook
    \textbf{4} \hspace{3mm}\emph{a hard stone}\\%rock
    \textbf{5} \hspace{3mm}\emph{a man's name}\\%rick
    \textbf{6 \hspace{3mm}Finish}\\
\end{TAB}

\vspace*{3mm}
\normalsize \textbf{\textsc{Hint}} If you do not know a word, try a word further down the puzzle. Often, you can work out which letter to change. 
    
    \vspace*{5mm}
    \Large{\textbf{You Try}}\\\normalsize
    Go from \textbf{note} to \textbf{tune} in six steps.
    \vspace*{5mm}       

\large
\begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){|c:c:c:c|}{|c:c:c:c:c:c:c|}
    \textbf{N} & \textbf{O} & \textbf{T} & \textbf{E} \\
    &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &  \\ 
    &   &   &  \\   
    &   &   &  \\
    \textbf{T} & \textbf{U} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{E}
\end{TAB}
%
\hspace*{5mm}
\large
\begin{TAB}(@,9cm,1cm){l}{|c:c:c:c:c:c:c|}
    \textbf{Start}\\
    \textbf{1} \hspace{3mm}\emph{zero things}\\%none
    \textbf{2} \hspace{3mm}\emph{ice-cream}\\%cone
    \textbf{3} \hspace{3mm}\emph{the centre of something}\\%core
    \textbf{4} \hspace{3mm}\emph{make someone healthy}\\%cure
    \textbf{5} \hspace{3mm}\emph{a square object}\\%cube
    \textbf{6} \hspace{3mm}\textbf{Finish}\\
\end{TAB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wrapfig shouldn't be used near lists, and center is internally a list. I would avoid wrapfig for this type of layout, it is rather difficult to handle, it is easier to place the figure manually. Side remark: font size commands don't take an argument, you should use `{\Huge text\par}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comment. How does one (a beginner) place a figure manually?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591115/how-to-put-side-caption-in-a-figure-that-is-wrapped-inside-a-a-text/591155?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#591155 for an example of manually placing the figure.