# adding text in a specific position in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, text

I have this slide and I wish not to change the composition. I would like to add the author of the image in a specific position (the red rectangle), i.e. **M.C. Escher, Relativity (1953)**

```
\frame{\frametitle{Introduzione}
    \justifying
    \scriptsize 

\vspace{-0.25cm}
Aggarwal, C. C., Hinneburg, A., Keim, D. A. 2001. \emph{On the surprising behavior of distance metrics in high dimensional space}. In International conference on database theory, pp. 420-434. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. (\emph{1859 citazioni su Google Scholar nel maggio 2021})
\vspace{-0.25cm}
% \vspace{-0.35cm}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale =0.155]{Escher.jpg}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-0.35cm}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest trying with the  `copyrightbox` package.

Comment: One solution is to use `tikzmark` package to declare your picture as a node (with `tikzmarnode`), then overlay another node anchored `south east` to place theauthor name.

Comment: Thanks, but looks not easy at all

Comment: For text positioning try the `textpos` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `\rlap` after the `\includegraphics`, on a full-width figure will ensure that the image remains centered.  As presently configured, the baselines of the image and the annotation are the same.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
    
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{caption} % better control of captions
\captionsetup[figure]{textfont={scriptsize,it}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduzione}
    {\scriptsize    Aggarwal, C. C., Hinneburg, A., Keim, D. A. 2001. \emph{On the surprising behavior of distance metrics in high dimensional space}. In International conference on database theory, pp. 420-434. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. (\emph{1859 citazioni su Google Scholar nel maggio 2021}) }   
    
    \begin{figure}
            \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,  height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\rlap{\quad\scriptsize\Longstack[l]{M.C. Escher\\Relativity (1953)}}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps one of the simplest methods.
[image: B]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
    
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}   
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption} % better control of captions
\captionsetup[figure]{textfont={scriptsize,it}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduzione}
    {\scriptsize    Aggarwal, C. C., Hinneburg, A., Keim, D. A. 2001. \emph{On the surprising behavior of distance metrics in high dimensional space}. In International conference on database theory, pp. 420-434. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. (\emph{1859 citazioni su Google Scholar nel maggio 2021}) }   
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.80\textwidth}
            \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,  height=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}      
            \caption*{M.C. Escher, Relativity (1953)} \label{fig:01}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29163/161015

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an object at an arbitrary position in the slide, you can use tikz with overlay option:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduzione}
  \justifying
  \scriptsize 
  \vspace{-0.25cm}
  Aggarwal, C. C., Hinneburg, A., Keim, D. A. 2001. \emph{On the surprising 
  behavior of distance metrics in high dimensional space}. In International 
  conference on database theory, pp. 420-434. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. 
  (\emph{1859 citazioni su Google Scholar nel maggio 2021})
  \vspace{-0.25cm}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,  height=0.6\textwidth]{example-image.png}
  \end{figure}
  \vspace{-0.35cm}
  %
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture,
    shift=(current page.south west),
    x=(current page.south east), y=(current page.north west),
  ]{
    \node[align=left]at (0.9,0.1) {M.C. Escher,\\Relativity (1953)}; 
    % Optional help grid lines
    %\draw[step=.1, opacity=0.3, thick, red] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The coordinates `(0.9,0.1)` are absolute with respect to the below left corner to the slide and are normalized (coordinate `(1,1)` is the upper right corner)

You can uncomment he code below `Optional help grid lines` in order to draw grid lines for guessing that coordinates:

[image]

Of course, you can define new commands for this:

```
\newcommand{\posabs}[2][]{
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture,
    shift=(current page.south west),
    x=(current page.south east), y=(current page.north west),
    #1
  ]{#2}
}
\newcommand{\postextabs}[4][align=left]{
  \posabs{\node[#1] at (#2,#3) {#4};}
}
```

This add tikz code at an arbitrary position:

```
\posabs[red]{\node[circle, fill=red] at (0.5,0.5) {};}
```

This add a text node at an arbitrary position:

```
\postextabs[red]{0.5}{0.5}{\huge !!}
```