# How to add a legend next to a figure in latex

Tags: legend, floats

I created a 4-subfigures figure:

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
  \caption{1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.png}
  \caption{2}
  \label{fig: 2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.png}
  \caption{3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4.png}
  \caption{4}
  \label{fig: 4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{process}
\label{fig: process}
\end{figure*}
```

I want to add a legend on the right of this figure, how can I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{1.png}
  \caption{1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{SCfigure}

.....

\begin{SCfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{4.png}
  \caption{4}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{subfigure}
\end{SCfigure}


\end{document}
```

Or You can implement suggestions from this similar question-answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Which comments are for right hand side legend?

Comment: Didn't understand what are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear. Missed are information about your document layout, how and where side legend is positioned etc.

I guess that you have two column document and that you like to have sub images in two rows. If I'm right, than expected result is something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{subcaption}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.74\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{subcaption 1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{subcaption 2}
  \label{fig: 2}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{subcaption 3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{subcaption 4}
  \label{fig: 4}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\textwidth}
\textbf{Legend:}

descriptions of sub images contents, probably with text in many lines
\end{minipage}

\caption{Process}
\label{fig: process}
    \end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```