Add figure caption on the right
I am trying to add the caption for my figure to the center right of the figure, such that the figure itself is half of the page width and the caption starts very close to it (i.e. there is little white space in between). But I can't seem to get it right. I tried this:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}} % Removes space between columns
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth,height=0.275\textheight]{new-particle-limits.png}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
            \captionsetup{skip=0pt} % Remove space between figure and caption
            \caption{This is a caption closely aligned to the right of the figure.}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

but the caption ends up on bottom right. And this:
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} % Width of the figure
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth,height=0.275\textheight]{new-particle-limits.png}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth} % Width of the caption
        \caption{This is a caption closely aligned to the right of the figure.}
    \end{minipage}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

where the caption in on center right as desired, but there is a large gap between the caption and the figure which I can't fix. What should I do?

\columnwidth and \textwidth change inside a minipage.  You can use [valign=c] (adjustbox package) instead of a minipage for \includgraphics.  You should make the width of the caption minipage to be {\dimexpr \linewidth-0.5\columnwidth-\columnsep} and add \hfill between.

@JohnKormylo thanks for the reply, but I am a bit confused. Could you post it as a full answer with the lines of code you mentioned inserted (also I can't choose your answer as the correct one in this form, either).

@Silviu Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. I think it's very likely that John would have posted a full answer directly if there had been an MWE in your question instead of just a snippet of code.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure this will helps

@MadyYuvi I tend to agree that this is a duplicate, but the answers currently don't show examples for vertical centering of image and caption. So I'm not sure.

Depending on the used class and the package for floats or caption there can be different solutions to solve your problem. Unfortunately you've not shown a minimal working example, so this answer is more a general one and don't need to show the best solution for your real case.
What you want is very easy using a KOMA-Script class like scrartcl. KOMA-Script provides an environment captionbeside to place a caption beside the content of a table or figure. For the vertical alignment you can either use \raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics{…}} or — more convenient — package adjustbox:
\documentclass[captions=centeredbeside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}% only for demonstration

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{captionbeside}
        {This is a caption closely aligned to the right of the figure.}
        [r]% caption right beside the content
        \adjincludegraphics[valign=c,width=0.6\columnwidth,max height=0.275\textheight]{example-image}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}


When using, e.g., a standard class or another compatible class, there are several packages like floatrowbytocbasic, floatrow, sidecap to place captions beside a figure. Here one suggestion:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrowbytocbasic}
\usepackage{mwe}% only for demonstration

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\floatbox[\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center}}]{figure}[.6\textwidth]
  {
    \caption{This is a caption closely aligned to the right of the figure.}
  }
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.275\textheight]{example-image}
  }
\end{figure}
  
\blindtext
\end{document}


Note: If you use a package that is incompatible with tocbasic you can replace floatrowbytocbasic with floatrow in this example.

While there are packages which provide captions beside images, they are neither needed nor difficult to replace.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=0.275\textheight, valign=c]{example-image}
    \hfill% add gap
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-\columnsep}% remaining width
        \hrule% to show actual size of caption
        \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, skip=0pt, justification=raggedright}% for short captions
        \caption{This is a caption closely aligned to the right of the figure.}
        \hrule% remove from final version
        \label{fig:example}% uses local definitions
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


